# What is the persist function doing in my DAO?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm using this tutorial: http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse/ee/ejb

Is the persist function required?  The class isn't extending any other classes.

Is DAO required in my model name?  I see `List<Guest>` is `<Guest>` referring to `GuestDao` or the package name?  If I had to guess I'd say `GuestDao`

Thanks for clearing this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `persist` method is a type-safe `persist` method. It can cut down one type of programming error (saving the wrong entity type through the DAO).

It's required in the sense that a `GuestDao` would be expected to have `Guest`-specific methods.

It also keeps knowledge of the persistence mechanism itself out of the mainline code: separation of concerns. All the mainline code needs to do is persist guests via the DAO.

`Dao` is not required in the model name. It would actually be confusing, since it wouldn't be a DAO. `Guest` refers to a guest. `GuestDao` refers to a DAO for `Guest`s.

`List<Guest>` refers to a collection of guests. `List` is a [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) type, the symbol between the `"<>"` is the collection type, in this case, `Guest`. `Guest` refers to exactly that--the `Guest` class.

Comment: Are you saying this is a bad tutorial since it uses `GuestDAO` ?  I'm definitely open to JAVA EE tutorial recommendations

Comment: @Webnet I don't know if the tutorial is good or bad. Why would using `GuestDao` be bad? It's a DAO for `Guest`s.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `List<?>` is the type.

There should be another domain class called `Guest`. Is it mentioned in the tutorial or earlier? `Guest` class should contain all the attributes of the `Guest` domain class, i.e. `name`, `telephoneNo` etc.